# Regression results returning 0 in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, regression

I am brand new to SAS  .  I'm trying to create dummy variables in SAS and run regression. After doing some research, I put the following codes together, but the results are showing 0 for a few Col. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks !

```
proc glmmod data = Work.Cost outdesign= GLMDesign outparm=GLMParm;

class  sex age Membership; model amount=sex age ;

run;

proc print data=GLMDesign ; run; proc print data=GLMParm ; run;


proc reg data=GLMDesign; DummyVars: model amount = COL1-COL69; ods select ParameterEstimates;

quit;
```

Comment: Did you reduce the dummy variables to N-1 for each categorical variable? I don't think GLMMOD does that part for you.

Comment: sorry, I just started using SAS. not sure what you mean

Comment: You don't need to fix anything the 0s are expected.  You would have the same Estimates if you used GLM and CLASS statement just as in your GLMMOD.  Why are you creating dummies and using REG?

Comment: When you have dummy variables, you need N-1, so if you have a variable that has 3 levels, you need two dummy variables. If you include all 3, one will end up being used as the reference and that variable will have a 0/missing parameter estimate since it's included in the intercept term.